# Java Swing - Redrawing from handler class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, actionevent

So I'll start off with putting my code here for my two classes.

SquareSimp.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SquareSimp
{

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        FilledFrame frame = new FilledFrame();

        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}

class FilledFrame extends JFrame
{
    int size = 400;

    public FilledFrame()
    {
        JButton butSmall   = new JButton("Small");
        JButton butMedium  = new JButton("Medium");
        JButton butLarge   = new JButton("Large");
        JButton butMessage = new JButton("Say Hi!");

        SquarePanel panel = new SquarePanel(this);
        JPanel butPanel = new JPanel();

        butSmall.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler1(this, 200){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                size = 200;
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });

        butMedium.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler1(this, this.size){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                size = 300;
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });

        butLarge.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler1(this, this.size){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                size = 400;
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });



        butPanel.add(butSmall);
        butPanel.add(butMedium);
        butPanel.add(butLarge);
        butPanel.add(butMessage);
        add(butPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize( size+100, size+100 );
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Exercise 2.
        //Anonymous implementations of listeners are very efficient when you do not need to pass parameters to the
        // constructor of the implemented listener.
        butMessage.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                // An anonymous function. Creates an actionListener that shows a dialog.
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hiiii");
            }
        });

    }

}

class SquarePanel extends JPanel
{
    FilledFrame theApp;

    SquarePanel(FilledFrame app)
    {
        theApp = app;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(20, 20, theApp.size, theApp.size);
    }
}
```

ButtonHandler1.java

```
package Lab2;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
// This is a class whose object will handle the event.
public class ButtonHandler1 implements ActionListener{
    private FilledFrame theApp;
    private int theSize;
    ButtonHandler1(FilledFrame app, int size){
        theApp = app;
        theSize = size;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    }

}
```

So far, it all works, which is great. However, as requirement I was asked to make one button handler for each class. Can someone explain to me what my buttonHandler is actually doing here? As I feel like instead of making anonymous functions, and overriding the actionPerformed event, I could have done it a better way (creating the event in the buttonhandler class and affecting the size from there based on what button is pressed). I do not know how to do this, so any help with an explanation would be great!

Thanks very much!

Brandon

Answer (score 0):

Any handler of a `*Listener` is used to handle `events` generated from the object which is being listened too.  In the main program, it appears that you have several buttons which alter the size of the window.

In the case of your class which implements buttonHandler, you aren't doing anything because your `actionPerformed` method is not doing anything.

And `anonymous classes` are an acceptable way of implementing listeners.  However, I prefer to use `inner classes` because the are cleaner (imho) and still have access to the `state` of the `enclosing class`.

Here is how your handler class should look:

```java
// This is a class whose object will handle the event.
class ButtonHandler1 implements ActionListener {
   private FilledFrame theApp;
   private int         theSize;

   ButtonHandler1(FilledFrame app, int size) {
      theApp = app;
      theSize = size;
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
      theApp.size = theSize;
      theApp.repaint();
   }
}
```

And here are the calls that add that handler to your buttons.

```java
      butSmall.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler1(this, 200));
      butMedium.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler1(this, 300));
      butLarge.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler1(this, 400));
```

Comment: How would you say I should alter the code? Would you say I should make ButtonHandler1 an inner class within SquareSimp?

Answer (score 0):

`ButtonHandler1` is not really used because the parameters passed to it are never used, and its single method is overridden when you construct it. 
So this:

```
     butSmall.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler1(this, 200){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                size = 200;
                panel.repaint();
            }
      });
```

Can be written without constructing `ButtonHandler1`:

```
    butSmall.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            size = 200;
            panel.repaint();
        }
    });
```

Or by using a lambda expression :

```
    butSmall.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
        size = 200;
        panel.repaint();
    });
```

There are many ways you could achieve the functionality you want. Based on what you wrote, you could define `ButtonHandler1` like so:

```
class ButtonHandler1 implements ActionListener{
    private final FilledFrame theApp;
    private final int theSize;
    ButtonHandler1(FilledFrame app, int size){
        theApp = app;
        theSize = size;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        theApp.size = theSize; //better use a setter in FilledFrame
        theApp.repaint();
    }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
    butSmall.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler1(this, 200));

    butMedium.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler1(this, 300));

    butLarge.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler1(this, 400));
```

Making `ButtonHandler1` an inner class in `FilledFrame` makes things simpler:

```
class ButtonHandler1 implements ActionListener{
    private final int theSize;
    ButtonHandler1(int size){
        theSize = size;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        size = theSize;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Use it by:

```
    butSmall.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler1(200));

    butMedium.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler1(300));

    butLarge.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler1(400));
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps. There are a number of ways I could do this, although I was asked to provide a separate buttonhandler that can handle all three of the buttons. Would you say I should use an inner class to create the button handler ?

Comment: If you used an inner class you would not have to pass a reference to access the size field.  But the way you did it is fine.

Comment: And one more note, unrelated to your actual problem.  It is considered bad practice to extend JFrame unless you are overriding something.  It is usually best to put a JPanel in JFrame and override that and do your painting, etc in that panel. Instead of extending JFrame, just use an instance of it.

Comment: @WJS of course. I think the OP is required to use a separate class. It might be a false assumption. I also assume that the comment about extending `JFrame` is aimed at the OP.

Comment: @c0der  Yes!  It is possible that is what the OP was taught.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the question but there are 2 ways to refactor your code:

1. Remove your `ButtonHandler1` class altogether and implement all of the logic in the anonymous class:

```
    //FilledFrame.java

    butSmall.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                    FilledFrame.this.size = 200;
                    panel.repaint();
                }
            });
```

2. You can add some getter and setter methods on your `FilledFrame` class and call these in `ButtonHandler1.actionPerformed` to implement the logic there like the following:

```
    package Lab2;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    // This is a class whose object will handle the event.
    public class ButtonHandler1 implements ActionListener{
        private FilledFrame theApp;
        private int theSize;
        ButtonHandler1(FilledFrame app, int size){
            theApp = app;
            theSize = size;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            theApp.setSizeMember(200); //do not use theApp.setSize(), create a method with a different name
            theApp.getSquarePanel().repaint();
        }

    }
```

I leave creating getters/setters on `FilledFrame` to you.